# How to send data to backend (heroku) for a multi-page signup page using Dio package?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dio

I am trying to write a signup page using Flutter's Dio package. It is multi-page which consists of: selecting your email, school, interest categories, and date of birth. User will be proceeded to the next page after completing the previous page. I want all the data to be posted to /user/register API of USER API once the user completes the last page, which is the dob page. How should I implement such signup page? Is there any example? I would like your help. Thank you.

Comment: Pass one page data to another page as a argument and in last page you got all data then do API call.

Comment: would you please give me an example? or any tutorial?

Comment: Which state management did you use for navigate to one screen to other

Comment: I think I will use riverpod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can share more details or screenshots about what you want, you can reach much healthier and more accurate answers. I'll still try to be as helpful as possible.

You can trigger the code below when clicking the 'Save' button on the register page

```
  Future<bool> userSave(String email, String school, String interestCategories,
  DateTime dateOfBirth) async {
try {
  const String apiUrl = "your-api-url";
  var params = {
    "email": email,
    "school": school,
    "interestCategories": interestCategories,
    "dateOfBirth": dateOfBirth
  };
  Response response = await Dio().post(
    apiUrl,
    options: Options(headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
    }),
    data: jsonEncode(params),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} catch (e) {
  return false;
}
}
```

I prepared an example to be compatible with your screen, you can get the places you need from here

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController interestCategoriesController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController schoolController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime dateOfBirth = DateTime.now();
  bool apiResponse = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: mainArea(),
    );
  }

  Widget mainArea() {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text("Save"),
        onPressed: () async {
          apiResponse = await userSave(
              emailController.text,
              schoolController.text,
              interestCategoriesController.text,
              dateOfBirth);
          if (apiResponse == true) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondPage()),
            );
          } else {
            //You can show alerDialog for response is false
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> userSave(String email, String school, String interestCategories,
      DateTime dateOfBirth) async {
    try {
      const String apiUrl = "your-api-url";
      var params = {
        "email": email,
        "school": school,
        "interestCategories": interestCategories,
        "dateOfBirth": dateOfBirth
      };
      Response response = await Dio().post(
        apiUrl,
        options: Options(headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
        }),
        data: jsonEncode(params),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. So on the first page of the user registration page, you enter your email which filters your school name on listview (ex: ssmith@uf.edu), then you are directed to the verification code page to enter the 6 digit code you received. Once it's approved, you are directed to the categories page where you select whichever categories (they are in an array in a wrap widget) you are interested in, then click the "Next" button; The last page is selecting your date of birth using cupertino_date_textbox, then you are complete.

Comment: As far as I understand, the codes I have written will work for you. If there is a missing part, I can complete it.

Comment: so what about the data from the previous pages? i see that texteditingcontroller is in the home page but as you know, I have those in different pages? Thank u

Comment: My first screen contains email data, then the second one contains nickname, third for interests, then forth the DOB.

Comment: Sir, do you mind helping me with answering my latest question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71533116/how-to-get-data-from-api-and-print-it-in-a-list-then-post-to-a-different-api-f Thank you.